# Disabled attribute not properly setting in IE using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I believe this is only my second post, so here it goes.
I'm working on an HTML form that manages credit cards. The form has a javascript page that does all the validation and such for it when submitted. 
The zip code field on the Form has an onblur action that queries a database for the zip code to populate the city/country fields. In the database, there can be more than one location set up for a zip code, in which a floating div appears to let the user select which address they would like to use.

When it's run, it first disables all the fields on the form with this function piece:

```
for(f=0;f<document.forms.length;f++)
{
    for(i=0;i<document.forms[f].elements.length;i++)
    {
       if (document.forms[f].elements[i].disabled==true)
          keepDisabled += document.forms[f].name + document.forms[f].elements[i].name + "^";

       document.forms[f].elements[i].disabled=true;
    }
 }
```

Then when the user selects an address, it enables all the fields with this piece:

```
for(f=0;f<document.forms.length;f++)
{
    for(i=0;i<document.forms[f].elements.length;i++)
    {
       if (keepDisabled.indexOf("^"+document.forms[f].name+document.forms[f].elements[i].name+"^") == -1)
          document.forms[f].elements[i].disbaled=true;
    }
}
```

So the disabled = true should be skipped over for any elements in the keepDisabled variable. The odd thing is that it works fine in FireFox/Chrome, but in IE, it sorta half-enables the fields. The disables fields lose the grey-out, the input/text field can't be edited, which is still good, and the select only activates on a double click.

I've also tried using these disabling codes:

```
document.forms[f].elements[i].prop("disabled", "disabled");
document.forms[f].elements[i].attribute("disabled, "disabled");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It certainly isn't `disbaled`, but `disabled` ?

Comment: If you spell it right, it will work: `document.forms[f].elements[i].disabled = true;` Incidentally, you're working with DOM nodes, whereas `prop()` is a jQuery method (or at least *not* a method I've encountered in native JavaScript). And I have no idea where `attribute()` originates (unless you meant `attr()`, jQuery again). But jQuery methods and DOM methods aren't interchangeable.

Comment: Do you want jquery or javascript and which jquery and IE versions  you are using

Comment: David->Sorry, I did spell it right in my actual code.Yes I meant attr(). Thanks for the tip.
MESSIAH-> I'm using the latest versions of both (IE10), but I've checked back with IE8/9 and it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks to David, I was able to find a solution. As he said, I was using DOM nodes, so I switched to using .setAttribute("disabled", true);, which ended up working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged jQuery, go with:

```
$("#id").attr("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$("#id").attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, at least use prop() instead of attr() :)